# iOS UIWebView needs to launch specific URLs in separate browser

Tags: ios, mobile, uiwebview

I created an iOS app that uses a UIWebView to display a mobile website.  The mobile site shows a "back" button within the UIWebView for its web server serves, but some pages provide links that navigate to external websites.

I want to provide a "back" button on those pages to get back to the original web server, but if I can't do this then I would like to launch these external sites in the standard browser in such a way that the user can still navigate the original site in the UIWebView using the "back" button already being displayed by the mobile site.

As it stands, my app cannot navigate back to the mobile site once a user clicks one of these "external" links because those sites do not display a back button to get back to the mobile app.  How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can't you just add a button to the UI and hook it up to `[webView goBack];`?

Comment: Well the "client" area already has a "back" button that is served as part of the mobile site's web pages.  I think it would be bad UI design to have two back buttons.  Besides, I have no control over what the mobile site is serving, but I do have control over the iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delegate `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`  and open the external URL's in the safari using 
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http:/wwww.extrenalurls.com"]]`

Comment: This answer works if I take the "open in safari" route, but how would I do it if I want to keep everything inside my own app?

Comment: you can have a `UIViewController` with `UIWebView` whenever you need to open the external link open it with the help of this.Also add options for **back** and **previous**.

Comment: I figured as much, but do you recommend an additional button at the top of the screen that allows the user to completely exit that external website in the second UIViewController and return to the mobile web site in the original UIViewController?  Thanks again.